# Understanding how the data loading works in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to Kotlin and Android development, and I confuse about something. Coming from NodeJS, I understand a bit about the concept of async. But I don't know about how state and async it works in Kotlin.

So I have this data class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "counters")
data class Counter(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0,
    var name: String,
)
```

and I made this Dao:

```
@Dao
interface CounterDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM counters")
    suspend fun getAllCounters(): List<Counter>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertCounter(counter: Counter): Int

    @Update
    suspend fun updateCounter(counter: Counter)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteCounter(counter: Counter)
}
```

Also I've made this Service

```
class CounterService(context: Context) {
    private val database = DatabaseProvider.provideDatabase(context)
    private val counterDao = database.counterDao

    suspend fun getAllCounters(): List<Counter> {
        return counterDao.getAllCounters()
    }
}
```

I've successfully add, remove, update the contents, and observe the state of this in my viewModel class utilizing this variable.

```
private var counters: SnapshotStateList<Counter> = mutableStateListOf()
```

Now I want to integrate to `RoomDatabase` and the current viewModel. So, how do I run `getAllCounters()` and transfer the stream to `counters` variable as it loaded? Or is there another way to transfer the data from local storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the declaration of `getAllCounters` in your `CounterDao` and `CounterService` to:

```
fun getAllCounters(): Flow<List<Counter>>
```

This way you retrieve a *flow* of lists of counters. That is important if anything changes in your list: You will always get an updated list everytime anything changes in the database. That is what the flow is for.

Handling flows in Compose is very simple: In your view model, you introduce a new variable that is defined as follows (with `service` as an instance of `CounterService`):

```
val counters: StateFlow<List<Counter>> = service.getAllCounters()
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = emptyList(),
    )
```

A `StateFlow` is a special type of flow that only contains the *newest* value of the underlying flow.

In your composable, you can now declare your `counters` variable like this (with `viewModel` as an instance of your view model):

```
val counters: List<Counter> by viewModel.counters.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

You need to use the dependency `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose` in gradle for this.  What this does is that it retrieves the current value from the view model's state flow and saves it in compose state object. Then its value is delegated (by the `by` keyword) to the `counters` variable. That variable now always contains the current list of counters that is stored in the database. If that list is changed in the database, this variable automatically updates. You can now use `counters` to display the list in Compose as you like.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand a bit. But I will need to try it in my code. Anyway, what is 5_000 for? Also, what is the difference between stateflow and statelist? Also, as I understand, suspend fun is kinda async, so the Flow will handle as it happens, and relay to compose. Is it correct?

Comment: The 5000 means don’t let the StateFlow go dormant unless it has no subscribers for 5 seconds. This is to handle the situation where the user rotates the screen and the activity gets recreated. It will lose one subscriber and get a new one quickly so we don’t want to waste resources letting it go dormant and then having to start back up again. In this case, starting back up again means it will repeat its database search to make sure it still has the most up to date value.

Comment: State list (mutableStateListOf) is a Compose-only construct. It doesn’t allow you to subscribe to it in general purpose code like you can with flows, but Compose code will automatically recompose when its contents change. It is more efficient than a `MutableStateFlow<List>` when you are changing only one item of the list at a time, but it’s not a practical option when your lists are coming from Room.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ah ok.. Actually, this is only an experiment as I learn Android programming, and it only contains one button to increase its value per counter. And I was only trying to persist the value so that it persists when the app launched again. I will try `StateFlow` method as I think I would need to use this some time in the future. But if I understand your explanation correctly, for the purpose of my experiment, `StateFlow` is too overkill. Is that right? but is there any other way you suggest to persist the value?

Comment: In my mind, I saw it something like I load the counter, and it appears on the screen when it is loaded, and 0 before the Dao finish loading. Then after Dao finish SELECT all the row, the number changed to the one persisted before.

Comment: If you’re using a database, I would say StateFlow is the best way to get the value back into your UI. It’s not overkill for a database. But if you are only storing a counter value, a database might be overkill. A database is for rows of data.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ah yes... in NodeJS, I could dump and load all states using sqlite module. I thought that I could do the same after I read about Room's backend. Is there any other method that you suggest? I would like to try it later after I succeed with this Room codes.

Comment: You can look up Jetpack data store preferences. It’s for storing simple bits of data. It is based on Flows, so you do need to understand them to use that. With both Room and that, you should read up on the difference between cold and hot flows. The flows in both behave similarly.

Answer (score -2):

As per my understanding you want to update your UI as data loads to the DB and you dont want to call this function everytime as that happens? If so please refer to the answer below:

Please wrap your return Type of List in your dao class to LiveData<List>
so initially when you call this method it returns you the data in RoomDb wrapped around LiveData which you can observe in you activity with an observer , at any point of time when the data changes in your DB it may be update ,edit ,delete anything , you will get a callback with updated list , with this data you can update your DB

HighLevel flow will be

Activity (with livedataObserver ) <- viewModel (with viewModelScope co-routine since you are using suspend functions) <- Respository/Service <- Dao <- RoomDb

Comment: Why the code formatting all the way? It's totally unreadable.